# HTML/CSS How to stretch a DIV vertically

Tags: css, html, vertical-alignment, stretch

I'm using DIVs to build something similar to a table, and I need to stretch my DIVs to match the height of its neighbor, in order to get my background-color to display correctly.

Here is my example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Some title</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <div style="float:left; width: 49%; background-color: #ced6eb;">
                Line1
                <br/>
                Line2
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; width: 49%; background-color: #dcddde; ">
                Only one line here
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
        <div>
            <div style="float:left; width: 49%; background-color: #ced6eb;">
                Something else
            </div>
            <div style="float:left; width: 49%; background-color: #dcddde;">
                Something else
            </div>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I need is to have the gray background on all 3 lines on the right, instead of getting a blank line in the middle.

This is a simplified version of my HTML.  The top left DIV (line1, line2) is of variable length, so a fixed attribute like `height:30px` is not an acceptable solution.

Thanks !

Yves

Comment: Rather than trying to equalise the div heights, you can achieve your goal in a simpler fashion. Simply add a `background-color` of `#dcddde` to your `div`s, the cascading order will take care of the rest. I can't post an answer as your question has been marked as a duplicate, but here: https://codepen.io/Skibbereen-Coderdojo/pen/xgNPxo (I've removed inline stying as its too difficult for me to work with)

Answer (score 1):

Hi I recommend reading up on [equal height columns](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/equal-height-columns-cross-browser-css-no-hacks)

This question has been discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122381/how-to-force-child-div-to-100-of-parents-div-without-specifying-parents-heigh), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1493310/how-can-you-force-a-floating-div-to-be-the-height-of-its-parent)