# Div height doesn't adjust to fit content

Tags: css, height, center, vertical-alignment

How can I center a div horizontally and vertically and adjust height to fit content?

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HCnbk/3/)

Here is my html code:

```
 <div class="sprite">
  </div>

 <div class="content">
     <span>close</span>
     <div class="centered">

         lorem lipsum.....

     </div>

 </div>
```

And css:

```
.sprite{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.content{
     border:1px solid red; 
     z-index:21; 
     position: absolute; 
     margin:auto; 
     padding:10px;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px; 
     bottom:0px; 
     right:0px;
     height:30%; 
     width:30%;  
     text-align:center; 
}
.content span{
     position:absolute; 
     top:0px; 
     right:0px;}

.centered{
     height:100%; 
/* Internet Explorer 10 */
     display:-ms-flexbox;
     -ms-flex-pack:center;
     -ms-flex-align:center;

/* Firefox */
    display:-moz-box;
    -moz-box-pack:center;
    -moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
    display:-webkit-box;
    -webkit-box-pack:center;
    -webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
   display:box;
   box-pack:center;
   box-align:center;
}
```

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get a div to resize its height to fit container?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1230354/how-to-get-a-div-to-resize-its-height-to-fit-container)

Answer (score 10):

Edit .content class to have following css and remove position absolute

```
height:auto;
overflow:visible;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your `.content`  class, remove 
 
                         `position: absolute;`
 
                          
and **add** 
 
                           `margin-top:24%;`
 to align it in vertically middle while taking the height of the content

`absolute` positioned attrib are rather difficult to style!

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/Xxfhn/

**EDIT**

Here you go mate

CSS to ammend :

```
  .sprite{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 20;
     width: 100%;
    /* height: 100%; */
    background-color: gray;
    opacity: 0.6;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    text-align:center;
}

.content{
     border:1px solid red; 
     position:relative;
     z-index: 21; /* change this to less than 20 to overlay under sprite on scroll*/
     margin:auto;
     padding:10px;
     width:30%;  
     margin-top:24%;
     text-align:center; 
}

.content span{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;text-align:right; border:1px solid #F00000}
```

**Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/Xxfhn/2/

Trick was to align a `absolute` `<span>` in `relative` `content` class....

Comment: Unfortunately no. The close span must be in corner of div with class 'content' and the sprite covers my content div.

Comment: yeah...got it...lemme try! :)

Comment: Thanks @Mayank! I'm waiting for the answer :)

Comment: The content div must be in center of page (so we cannot use  margin-top:24%; should be margin:auto) And I still see that the sprite covers the content panel. Any idea?

Comment: final..edited code above...`http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/Xxfhn/2/` .....margin :0 will push it to top because of positioning...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42138/discussion-between-mayank-and-otix)

Answer (score 0):

```
.content{
     border:1px solid red; 
     position:relative;

     margin:auto;
     padding:10px;
     width:30%;  
     margin-top:4%;
     text-align:center; 
}

.content span{position:absolute;right:0;top:0;text-align:right;}

.sprite{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;

     width: 100%;

    background-color: gray;
    opacity: 0.6;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
    text-align:center;
}
```

does that help

Answer (score -1):

replace your `css` with mine...

```
.sprite{
    position: fixed;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    z-index: 20;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    opacity: 0.6;
}

.content{
     border:1px solid red; 
     z-index:21; 
     position: absolute; 
     margin:auto; 
     padding:10px;
     left: 0px;
     top: 0px; 
     bottom:0px; 
     right:0px;

     width:30%;  

     text-align:center; 
}

.content span{position:absolute; top:0px; right:0px;}

.centered{

/* Internet Explorer 10 */
display:-ms-flexbox;
-ms-flex-pack:center;
-ms-flex-align:center;

/* Firefox */
display:-moz-box;
-moz-box-pack:center;
-moz-box-align:center;

/* Safari, Opera, and Chrome */
display:-webkit-box;
-webkit-box-pack:center;
-webkit-box-align:center;

/* W3C */
display:box;
box-pack:center;
box-align:center;
}
```

Comment: The height of div with class content must be equal with height of div with class centered. In your case the height is 100%.

Comment: isn't that what u wanned.. ??

Comment: see the picture attached in first post.

Answer (score -2):

You are making this hard on yourself, just change the Position to be Relative in the class content, see below;

```
 .content{
 border:1px solid red; 
 z-index:21; 
 position: absolute; 
 margin:auto; 
 padding:10px;
 left: 0px;
 top: 0px; 
 bottom:0px; 
 right:0px;
 height:30%; 
 width:30%;  
 text-align:center; 
 }
```

Comment: Your answer says `position: absolute; ` not relative.

Comment: Why are you commenting 6 months later? Kind of missed the timing on this @Matt. Plus I was mentioning what to fix and where if you read my comments.